# jQuery forms Upload Progress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms

Hello I am trying to figure out how to fix this upload progress bar so that it works in  Firefox.

In Firefox it only goes to around 90 % in chrome it displays progress at 100 %

Any ideas are greatly appreciated

*cheers

Edit I should mention this is uses the jQuery form plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Edit Not sure what I did but it now sets the status to 99 % any ideas how to get it to 100% in firefox :-)

I have updated the code below

code below

```
<style>
<!--
/*form {display: block; background: #333; padding: 15px}*/

.progress {margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto; position:relative; width:400px; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 1px; border-radius: 3px;}
.bar {margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto;background-color: #B4F5B4; width:0%; height:20px; border-radius: 3px; }
.percent {position:absolute; display:inline-block; top:3px; left:48%;}
-->
</style>
```

and the jQuery

```
        <div class="progress">
        <div class="bar"></div >
        <div class="percent">0%</div >
    </div>
    <div id="status"></div>


<script type='text/javascript'>
<!--  

jQuery('document').ready(function() {
    var bar = $('.bar');
    var percent = $('.percent');
    var status = $('#status');   
        $('form').ajaxForm({
            dataType: 'script',
            url: "{{=URL('default', 'user_song_form')}}",
            beforeSend: function() {
                status.empty();
                var percentVal = '0%';
                bar.width(percentVal)
                percent.html(percentVal);
            },             
            uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                bar.width(percentVal)
                percent.html(percentVal);
            },
            complete: function(xhr) {
                status.html('Thank You Upload Complete!');
            }     
        });         
   });     
-->

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

the simplest way is to use an uploader i recommend

http://fineuploader.com/

and the cool about it is that No required external dependencies

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem I was having with the upload status by changing the complete function

the jQuery code now looks like the following

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
<!--  

jQuery('document').ready(function() {
    var bar = $('.bar');
    var percent = $('.percent');
    var status = $('#status');   
        $('form').ajaxForm({
            dataType: 'script',
            url: "{{=URL('default', 'user_song_form')}}",
            beforeSend: function() {
                status.empty();
                var percentVal = '0%';
                bar.width(percentVal)
                percent.html(percentVal);
            },             
            uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                bar.width(percentVal)
                percent.html(percentVal);
            },
            complete: function(xhr) {
                var percentVal = '100%';
                bar.width(percentVal)
                percent.html(percentVal);
                status.html('Thank You Upload Complete!');
            }     
        });         
   });     
-->

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using uploadify as an alternative. It works very well and works in IE and Firefox 100%

http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: I tried getting uploadify to work for 3 days but kept getting an HTTP Error or IO Error, I read several posts on it nothing was able to solve it. So at this point I have nothing good to say about Uploadify, and Flash does not work in most mobile platforms... Anyway ty :-)